# Regex is getting false positives in anti-spam script

Tags: php, regex

I wrote some added conditions to eliminate  some of the spam I was receiving on my website. It has massively reduced the abuse, but there are some test cases of false positives. Does anyone have suggestions on how to avoid some of these?

First, the the code searches the message to make sure none of the specific key words are included. Then, two regular expressions are used.

Some of the spam was coming in the form of a random word, character, and integer string of 4+ digits, so the first regex checks and blocks those scenarios. However, when a user cites another users post, it uses the chars '>> + the post number', which was returning false positives.

I added another condition for handling that,  in which a posts containing >> plus 3 or more digits would be ignored.

So far the code mostly works, however in testing I have noticed that saying the sentence "I have 2000 chickens" reports a false positive, because space is included in the any character condition of the first regex. I could easily not count the space character here, but some of the spam was in that form ("randomword 23450").

My code so far:

```
foreach ($bannedwords as $bannedphrase) {
    //see if banned phrase is in the message body
    $pos = strpos($lowercaseBody, $bannedphrase);
    //if it is, or if it contains the regex expression, ban the user.
    if ($pos !== FALSE || preg_match('/.+\d{4}/', $lowercaseBody) && !preg_match('/[>>]+\d{3}/',  $lowercaseBody)){         
        require_once 'inc/mod/ban.php';
        Bans::new_ban($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'Suspected Spammer.', '86400', $_POST['board'] == '*' ? false : $_POST['board']);
        error($config['error']['bannedword']);
    }       
}
```

The expression [^ ]+\d{4} works to allow the false positive, but once again allows spam in the form of "random 3459".

Some of the examples that were posted from a spam bot were:
demetrius3204
dialog.2345
distance 33456
divinity$4598

Initially all of the posts had 5+ digits but it [or the spammer] became aware of my counter measures and changed to 4 digits, so I changed again which seemed to do the trick.

Then there are some posts, which come in like "weorasdsodfh" or "asdfjk"..

Comment: I think what you're trying to do may not be possible with regex, regex isn't smart. You should list out some examples on positives and negatives and see if there is a pattern.

Comment: With what's currently in place, I am waiting on new spam posts to arrive so that I can see what is and isn't currently handled. And, as a note, I changed the code in production to the version at the tail of the question, allowing the "i have 2000 chickens" post and thereby some spam, so that I could get some example spam without upsetting too many users.

Comment: Some of your spam seems to be jumbled garbage. Wouldn't you be better off using a dictionary of some sort? Personally, I'd not use a regex for filtering spam, I'd rather use something like [a Naive Bayes classifier.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)

Comment: This type of spam checking is notoriously error-prone. Your best bet to keep it working is to compile a large list of good and bad messages and keep running it through until they are all identified properly. Then keep that list updated

Comment: @SorinLascu, I will look into that. I guess using a dictionary would be a huge pain, because it would add alot of time to process making sure each word were real, depending on the size of the post. While I don't care about the spammers wasted time, I do care about the users

Comment: @DanSmith I assume you're running some kind of image board, right? That style of quoting seems typical of them. Have you tried looking into what other image boards have tried to do to combat spam? A rather more lenient one, 8chan requires completing a captcha once a day.

Comment: @SorinLascu, that is a correct assumption. I have operated one such chan for about 3 years, migrating back and forth between Kusaba - X and Tinyboard frameworks. Tinyboard/Vichan (current implimentation) comes with some  built in protection, double checking against DNSBL as a first layer. I saw that 8chan does that, and in fact a similar solution was suggested by one of the volunteer moderators. I plan on making that a long-term implimentation, but needed a short term fix to free up some of the moderators time while they continue to grow the community.

Comment: @DanSmith There are also a few more layers you can add like Akismet or Project Honeypot. I'm not sure how well they work in practice though.

Comment: @SorinLascu, I have used Project Honeypot in the past, but its results have shown to be more long time consuming before they really become noticeable. I will look into Akismet